# Change temp table column names based on corresponding column and record value

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a temp table which is imported into SQL and has column names such as...

`Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6`   and so on.

One record in the table contains the actual column names such as...

```
fldBP, fldDialysis, fldMed, fldInventory, fldDoctors
```

I need to loop through or create a basic query to changed each column name to that located in the column and record containing the real name. Is there a simple way of doing this? The record with the column names is always the first one.

Comment: there is no such a thing as "the first one" in terms of the position of the record in a RDBMS. It may look like it is the first one for some tables, but it may be elsewhere for others. What you really need to do is to fix your import routine to import the data properly

Comment: I think you used bulk insert to import that data and forgot to set property FIRSTROW = 2 , can you not just import the data again will save you a lot of pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have all the data in sql server no point importing it again, just use something like

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Field1)) Field1Len
      ,MAX(LEN(Field2)) Field2Len
      ,MAX(LEN(Field3)) Field3Len
FROM Table_Name
```

This will give you and approximate idea what length each column needs to be, Create A new Table using the column names from your table where you already have your data, and Delete that row, Then Simply do an Insert Into your new table something like this,,,

```
INSERT INTO New_Table (fldBP, fldDialysis, fldMed, fldInventory, fldDoctors,....)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6,......
FROM Table_Name

/*Finally Drop the stagging\Bad table*/

DROP TABLE Table_Name
```